# How to compare each of the values in two delimited strings?

Tags: infopath, infopath2010

I have two fields, each with a string delimited by semi-colons.
Is there a way to compare each value in one string to each value in the other string?

```
So if field one contains: String1;String2;String3
and field two contains: String4;String5;String6

then I would like to be able to compare String1 to String4 and String5 and String6
if String1 matches any of these values I would like it to return true. 

I also would need to compare Strings 2 and 3 to 4,5 and 6 in a similar manner.
```

I am looking for a solution that does not require Visual Studio Tools for Applications (VSTA).

EDIT: The number of strings in each field varies as it is being populated from an external datasource.

Answer (score 1):

You need at least five helper fields to store the text you want to compare.  Use rules that set these helper field values to the text between the semicolons. You will need a combination of Substring-before and Substring-after for that.

The Rules in sequence

Rule to split out the text:

- Set helper1 to `substring-before(Field1, ";")`
- Set helper2 to `substring-before(Field2, ";")`
- Set helper3 to `substring-before(substring-after(Field2, ";"), ";")`
- Set helper4 to `substring-after(substring-after(Field2, ";"), ";")`

Then run three rules to compare the values in helper1 to helper2/3/4

Rule 1

- runs if helper1 = helper2
- Set helper5 = true

Rule 2

- runs if helper1 = helper3
- Set helper5 = true

Rule 3

- runs if helper1 = helper4
- Set helper5 = true

The helper fields can be in a secondary data source used for form logic processing.

Comment: I probably should've mentioned that the number of strings in each field is variable. Whoops. I've added it to my post now. 
Although if the largest number of strings contained were... lets say 100, could I then use 100 fields to compare the values?

Comment: Whoops indeed. InfoPath has very limited tools for string processing. You may want to re-consider your data architecture. Without code this will be near impossible or at the least very labour intense to create that many rules.